# What file format will change from window to linux?

Tags: linux, window

I transferred the .zip file from the window computer to the linux server. Will the content of the file change? Could the file change directly because of the difference between window and linux, and it can no longer be used in linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the file will not change. It will contain the same sequence of bytes, yield the same `sha512sum` etc.

Comment: The ZIP itself will not and must not change. However, if you extract ZIP entries that are flagged as 'text' files, the extraction process _may_ change LF to CRLF or vice-versa in the extracted file(s), depending on the program and options you use.